# Upper bound for $\int_{c_0}^{+\infty} e^{-(x + c_1 x^{-c_2})} dx$

Tags: integration, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to place an upper bound on $$\int_{c_0}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(x + \frac{c_1}{x^{c_2}}\right)} dx, \ \ \ c_i > 0$$ in terms of $c_0, c_1, c_2$ which is at least asymptotically correct. A factor isn't significant. [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) is applicable with $M = c_1, h(x) = e^{-x}, g(x) = \frac{c_1}{x^{c_2}}$, but I was hoping to avoid the horrendous calculation for the relative error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the integral in the form
$$
\exp \left( { - \left( {c_0  + \frac{{c_1 }}{{c_0^{c_2 } }}} \right)} \right)\int_{c_0 }^{ + \infty } {\exp \left[ { - \left( {\left( {x + \frac{{c_1 }}{{x^{c_2 } }}} \right) - \left( {c_0  + \frac{{c_1 }}{{c_0^{c_2 } }}} \right)} \right)} \right]dx} .
$$
By the mean value theorem,
$$
\left( x + \frac{{c_1 }}{{x^{c_2 } }} \right) - \left( {c_0  + \frac{{c_1 }}{{c_0^{c_2 } }}} \right) > \left( {1 - \frac{{c_1 c_2 }}{{c_0^{c_2  + 1} }}} \right)(x - c_0 )
$$
for all $x>c_0$. Thus, an upper bound for your integral is
\begin{align*}
&\exp \left( { - \left( {c_0  + \frac{{c_1 }}{{c_0^{c_2 } }}} \right)} \right)\int_{c_0 }^{ + \infty } {\exp \left[ { - \left( {1 - \frac{{c_1 c_2 }}{{c_0^{c_2  + 1} }}} \right)(x - c_0 )} \right]dx} \\ &
 = \exp \left( { - \left( {c_0  + \frac{{c_1 }}{{c_0^{c_2 } }}} \right)} \right)\frac{1}{{1 - \frac{{c_1 c_2 }}{{c_0^{c_2  + 1} }}}},
\end{align*}
provided that $c_1 c_2 < c_0^{c_2  + 1}$. For large positive $c_0$, this is asymptotically sharp (it agrees with the leading order term coming from Laplace's method).

Comment: For large $c_1$ is the approach to break the integral up into three parts: $\int_{c_0}^{(c_1 c_2)^{1/(c_2+1)} - \epsilon} + \int_{(c_1 c_2)^{1/(c_2+1)} - \epsilon}^{(c_1 c_2)^{1/(c_2+1) + \epsilon}} + \int_{(c_1 c_2)^{1/(c_2+1) + \epsilon}}^{+\infty}$ since your method can be applied to the first and last term.

Comment: That case will be more involved.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{c_0}^\infty\exp \left(-(x+c_1x^{-c_2})\right)\,dx=\int_{c_0}^\infty e^{-x}e^{-\frac{c_1}{x^{c_2}}}\,dx$$
now since:
$$1\le e^{-\frac{c_1}{x^{c_2}}}\le e^{-\frac{c_1}{c_0^{c_2}}}$$
we can use the integral of $e^{-x}$ multiplied by these bounds